# Declaring a var in click function in jquery

Tags: jquery, variables

I have the following code:

```
$("#ca li").click(function(){
    $("#ca li").css('text-decoration','none');
    $(this).css('text-decoration','underline');
    var sec = $(this).html();    
});

if (sec == 'Africa') {
    var ar = 'this is';
} else {
    var ar = 'is that';
}
$('#co').html(ar);
```

The html:

```
<ul id='ca'>
    <li>Africa</li>
    <li>Americas</li>
    <li>Asia</li>
    <li>Europe</li>
    <li>Oceania<li>
</ul>
```

The var `sec` does not change after click. What can I do?

Comment: Declare it outside the function, remove the `var` or declare it as `window.sec`.

Comment: Exactly. This applies to `ar` as well.

Comment: For more information on variable scope, http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ecihay/7/edit)*

```
function changeText(sec){
  var ar = sec=='Africa' ? 'this is' : 'is that';
  $('#co').text(ar);  
}


$("#ca li").click(function(){
    $("#ca li").css('text-decoration','none');
    $(this).css('text-decoration','underline');
    var sec = $(this).text(); 
    changeText(sec);
});
```

Comment: the if and $('#co').html|() cannot be in the click function

Comment: because all this is in a keyup function

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to read more about javascript [variables scoping](http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/reference_js_intro_ex.html)

```
var sec; 
var ar;

$("#ca li").click(function(){
    $("#ca li").css('text-decoration','none');
    $(this).css('text-decoration','underline');
    sec = $(this).html(); 
});

ar = (sec == 'Africa') ? 'this is' : 'is that'; //ternary operator
$('#co').html(ar);
```

Just move the sec variable outside the function and it will work, otherwise it will live/exists inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ca li").click(function(){
    $("#ca li").css('text-decoration','none');
    $(this).css('text-decoration','underline');
    var sec = $(this).html();  
    if (sec == 'Africa') {
      var ar = 'this is';
     } else {
       var ar = 'is that';
     }
     $('#co').html(ar);  
});
```

I assume you want the value to change with the click event.. no?.. so put it inside the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sec;

$("#ca li").click(function(){
    $("#ca li").css('text-decoration','none');
    $(this).css('text-decoration','underline');
    sec = $(this).html();    
});

if (sec == 'Africa') {
    var ar = 'this is';
} else {
    var ar = 'is that';
}
$('#co').html(ar);
```

(This would be using global variables, and it works, but it is not considered good coding.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem as others have highlighted, is that you are declaring your variable inside the click closure. This means it is redefined every time the click handler fires and that it cannot be referenced from outside of the closure. We fix this by declaring the variable outside the closure. I have also brought the ar declaration to the top as this is best practice and you had a similar misuse of scope in your if(){}else(). This will solve your problem and make you linter compliant.

```
var sec, ar;

$("#ca li").click(function(){
    $("#ca li").css('text-decoration','none');
    $(this).css('text-decoration','underline');
    sec = $(this).html();    
});

if (sec == 'Africa') {
    ar = 'this is';
} else {
    ar = 'is that';
}
$('#co').html(ar);
```